# Python: trying to use third party libraries in git hooks

Tags: python, git, hook, githooks

I am trying to utilise the javalang module in my pre-commit hook but I get an error on the line where it is trying to install javalang.

I don't know why this is happening because I have installed javalang by using pip through my terminal.

I have attached a screenshot of the error, can anyone help identify how I can fix this issue?

EDIT: Here are the first lines of my hook

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import json
import javalang
import re
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
```

[image]

EDIT: I think I've found a very big clue. When I open my terminal and run my python 2.7 version - I can import javalang. However, if I run my python3 version - I cannot import javalang. This means that sourcetree must be executing python3. I previously installed javalang via pip. Does this mean it didn't get installed on my python 3? Only 2?

Comment: Are you sure you have only one version of python installed? It's not uncommon to have both python 2 and 3 installed and that leads to a lot of confusion. Also it could be helpful to share the code of your hook (at least the first lines up until the import)

Comment: @mathielo Please see my edit, the error happens on the import javalang line

Comment: Can you please share the output of `python --version`? I see `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of your script. It usually is python 2.x on systems where both python 2 and 3 are installed, but couldn't hurt to double check. If your default is python 3, `pip3 install javalang` should solve your problem.

Comment: @Shakkhar pip3 install javalang did solve my problem thank you. However, is there any way to know which version of python is executing my script? I have the shebang line at the top but I need to know which version of python has been found by that shebang line. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: You can stick an `import sys; print sys.version` in your script to check. If your code is not compatible with both 2 and 3, I recommend replacing your shebang with `/usr/bin/env pythonX` where `X` is the desired version.

Comment: @Shakkhar I don't want to restrict anyone on which python version to use.

Comment: @Shakkhar, why don't you post the answer?